# While compiling ASP.NET ecommerce website receive: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

I just partially added shopping cart to my ecommerce test-site.

It still can't do checkout, or even update quantity of items(about to start though) but I should be able to open the page responsible for displaying the shopping cart. Instead it bricks my entire website.

I get the following error when compiling the site:

> Server Error in '/Website' Application. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be
>   shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one
>   of the below steps, then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:
>
> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your
>   application:
>
> Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given
>   application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will
>   cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.
>
> Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a
>   memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application
>   has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    ShoppingCartAccess.get_shoppingCartId() +81
>   ShoppingCartAccess.GetItems() +57
>   UserControls_CartSummary.PopulateControls() +30
>   UserControls_CartSummary.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
>   +8991986    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2496
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

Judging from the stack trace error(and if I'm correct from judging the stack trace error) -  the error appears to happen with **ShoppingCartAccess.get_shoppingCartId()**. Threfore I'm including the code for the **ShoppingCartAccess.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ShoppingCartAccess
/// </summary>
public class ShoppingCartAccess
{
    public ShoppingCartAccess()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    // returns the shopping cart ID for the current user
    private static string shoppingCartId
    {
        get
        {
            // get the current HttpContext
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            // try to retrieve the cart ID from the user cookie
            string cartId = context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"].Value;
            // if the cart ID isn't in the cookie...
            {
                // check if the cart ID exists as a cookie
                if (context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"] != null)
                {
                    // return the id
                    return cartId;
                }
                else
                // if the cart ID doesn't exist in the cookie as well, generate
                // a new ID
                {
                    // generate a new GUID
                    cartId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    // create the cookie object and set its value
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Website_CartID", cartId);
                    // set the cookie's expiration date
                    int howManyDays = WebsiteConfiguration.CartPersistDays;
                    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(howManyDays, 0, 0, 0);
                    DateTime expirationDate = currentDate.Add(timeSpan);
                    cookie.Expires = expirationDate;
                    // set the cookie on the client's browser
                    context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    // return the CartID
                    return cartId.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add a new shopping cart item
    public static bool AddItem(string productId, string attributes)
    {
        // get a configured DbCommand object
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        // set the stored procedure name
        comm.CommandText = "ShoppingCartAddItem";
        // create a new parameter
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
        param.Value = shoppingCartId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = 36;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // create a new parameter
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ProductID";
        param.Value = productId;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // create a new parameter
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@Attributes";
        param.Value = attributes;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // returns true in case of success and false in case of an error
        try
        {
            // execute the stored procedure and return true if it executes
            // successfully, and false otherwise
            return (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm) != -1);
        }
        catch
        {
            // prevent the exception from propagating, but return false to
            // signal the error
            return false;
        }
    }


    // Update the quantity of a shopping cart item
    public static bool UpdateItem(string productId, int quantity)
    {
        // get a configured DbCommand object
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        // set the stored procedure name
        comm.CommandText = "ShoppingCartUpdateItem";
        // create a new parameter
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
        param.Value = shoppingCartId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = 36;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // create a new parameter
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ProductID";
        param.Value = productId;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // create a new parameter
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@Quantity";
        param.Value = quantity;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // returns true in case of success and false in case of an error
        try
        {
            // execute the stored procedure and return true if it executes
            // successfully, and false otherwise
            return (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm) != -1);
        }
        catch
        {
            // prevent the exception from propagating, but return false to
            // signal the error
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Remove a shopping cart item
    public static bool RemoveItem(string productId)
    {
        // get a configured DbCommand object
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        // set the stored procedure name
        comm.CommandText = "ShoppingCartRemoveItem";
        // create a new parameter
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
        param.Value = shoppingCartId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = 36;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // create a new parameter
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ProductID";
        param.Value = productId;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // returns true in case of success and false in case of an error
        try
        {
            // execute the stored procedure and return true if it executes
            // successfully, and false otherwise
            return (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm) != -1);
        }
        catch
        {
            // prevent the exception from propagating, but return false to
            // signal the error
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Retrieve shopping cart items
    public static DataTable GetItems()
    {
        // get a configured DbCommand object
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        // set the stored procedure name
        comm.CommandText = "ShoppingCartGetItems";
        // create a new parameter
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
        param.Value = shoppingCartId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = 36;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // return the result table
        DataTable table = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);
        return table;
    }

    // Retrieve shopping cart items
    public static decimal GetTotalAmount()
    {
        // get a configured DbCommand object
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        // set the stored procedure name
        comm.CommandText = "ShoppingCartGetTotalAmount";
        // create a new parameter
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
        param.Value = shoppingCartId;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Size = 36;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        // return the result table
        return Decimal.Parse(GenericDataAccess.ExecuteScalar(comm));
    }

}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be because the value of context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"] is null.

Write this line:

```
if(context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"]==null) return "0";
```

before this line:

```
string cartId = context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context.Request.Cookies["Website_CartID"].Value` looks suspicious. What if the cookie doesn't exist?